# Does data go from primary memory to CPU register directly without going to cache memory?

Tags: memory, cache, register

Does data go from the primary memory to CPU registers directly, when the CPU fetches data from the primary memory?

Or data has to go from the primary memory to the cache memory first, before going to the registers?

Comment: what do you mean by registers?

Comment: registers in CPU

Comment: Can you please re-type your question so we can actually help you? If you want to learn about CPU cache go [HERE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPU_cache)

Comment: I edited my post, and hope it is clearer.

Comment: Which CPU are you talking about?

Comment: @Ignacio: No specific CPU. Just general CPUs in most computers

Comment: "No specific CPU" behaves any possible way in the world.

Comment: CPUs have MANY different architectures. It's up to the design.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams: For example, the intel CPU in Thinkpad T400 laptop

Answer (score 1):

On most modern CPUs, it is the cache itself (and the hardware that surrounds it) that acquires the memory, not the core. It may acquire the memory from another cache or it may acquire it from the physical RAM chips. But it's not the execution core's problem. The cache and associated hardware [handles low-level memory coherence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MESI_protocol) operations.